# Be the same person to a remote git repository on multiple computers?

Tags: git, github, assembla

I develop on several machines, but I find that I have trouble when I push to a remote repository: It (currently Assembla but happened before on Github) thinks I'm a separate person. In Assembla I'm the "Anonymous" user even though I changed my global config to match my name and email and even used the same SSH key. While this is only annoying right now, it might be a bigger problem in the future when me or someone else needs to know everything I've contributed to a project.

How can I make a remote repository think I'm the same person when I'm on multiple computers?

As a side note: Is there any way to associate all previous commits (I'm the only person on this current project) with me?

Comment: are you sure you have both name and email the same on all computers in config ?

Comment: The only authorship information git stores is author/commiter name and email. If there's a difference with those identical, seems like it must be outside of git. Magic?

Comment: Related question: [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your previous commits using those instructions: http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

But be careful with pushed commits, in worst case you can mess up the repo.

Comment: If you do want to change history, you should do the change in one place, wipe everything else, and create fresh clones.